# Objective-C UIImage Concave Corner (aka Custom Progress Bar)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I need help creating this image programmatically in Objective-c. The concave radius is half the image's height.

[image: Box with circle taken out, than left side taken off]

My goal is to have a progress bar where the left side is an image, the middle is the containing view background color and the right side is a stretchable image.

[image: A color bar with the shape mentioned above at both ends]

---

**EDIT**

@Rob's solution is the way to go. However, I must be implementing it incorrectly.

I created the header and implementation files and added the class to an existing UIView, progressBarView. The CustomProgress views show up in IB and everything looks great...

[image: IB example]

...but when I try to set the value of progress with...

```
self.progressBarView.progress = 0.75;
```

...I get a `Property 'progress' not found on object of type 'UIView *'` semantic warning.

Comment: I’m assuming this is a compile-time warning? If so, I suspect that although you set the base class of your progress view, it would appear that your `IBOutlet` is defined as a `UIView` rather than a `CustomProgress`/`CustomProgressView`.

Comment: That indeed was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than creating any images at all, I might just apply a `cornerRadius` to the both the main progress view as well as the view that shows the progress. So, imagine the following view hierarchy:

[image]

The main progress view is that white bordered view in the back. That has a subview, the `progressSubview` (highlighted in blue, above), which shows the progress thus far (and will change as we update the `progress` property). And the green and blue views just fixed sized subviews of the `progressSubview` that are revealed as the `progressSubview`, which clips its subviews, changes size.

Applying corner radii is very easy. And by avoiding any images or custom `drawRect`, we can animate changes of the `progressSubview` if we want:

[image]

E.g.

```
//  CustomProgressView.h

@import UIKit;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface CustomProgressView : UIView

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat progress;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

And

```
//  CustomProgressView.m

#import "CustomProgressView.h"

@interface CustomProgressView ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView *progressSubview;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView *greenView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView *redView;

@end

@implementation CustomProgressView

- (instancetype)init {
    return [self initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        [self configure];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        [self configure];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)configure {
    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] init];
    subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    subview.clipsToBounds = true;
    self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1;

    UIView *redView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.redView = redView;

    UIView *greenView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    greenView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.greenView = greenView;

    [self addSubview:subview];
    [subview addSubview:redView];
    [subview addSubview:greenView];

    self.progressSubview = subview;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.layer.cornerRadius = MIN(self.bounds.size.height, self.bounds.size.width) / (CGFloat)2.0;
    self.progressSubview.layer.cornerRadius = MIN(self.bounds.size.height, self.bounds.size.width) / (CGFloat)2.0;
    [self updateProgressSubview];

    self.redView.frame = self.bounds;

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height);
    self.greenView.frame = rect;
}

- (void)setProgress:(CGFloat)progress {
    _progress = progress;
    [self updateProgressSubview];
}

- (void)updateProgressSubview {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.width * self.progress, self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height);
    self.progressSubview.frame = rect;
}

- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder {
    [super prepareForInterfaceBuilder];

    self.progress = 0.75;
}

@end
```

Then you can update the progress like so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    self.progressView.progress = 0.75;
}];
```

---

> ...I get a Property 'progress' not found on object of type 'UIView *' semantic warning

It would appear that your `IBOutlet` is defined as a `UIView` rather than a `CustomProgressView`.

Comment: Is there a reason for mixing "self." and "_"?

Comment: In `setProgress`, it’s critical to use `_progress` (because using `self.progress = ...` inside `setProgress` will end up calling `setProgress` again, causing infinite loop). But elsewhere, it’s prudent to use `self.progress` (and I have updated `updateProgressSubview`, above, accordingly).

Comment: So using "self." outside of setProgress: is a stylistic choice?

Comment: It's best practice, IMHO. 99% of the time, `self.progress` will just retrieve the contents of `_progress`, so they’re the same. But what, if at some future date, you decided to implement a custom getter that did something else/extra. If you used `_progress` ivar throughout your code, you’d have to go back through it and fix all of those references. If you always use the getter where you can, you future-proof your code. Think of the analogy of our custom setter. We did that and then you had some code that update `_progress` instead, our custom setter would be for naught. Same with getters.

Comment: See [Use Accessor Methods to Get or Set Property Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW5). In fact, where they talk about the fact that you can use the synthesized ivars, they say, “it’s best practice for an object to access its own properties using accessor methods or dot syntax...”.